# Understanding the jquery ui css file content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I noticed in the jquery.ui.theme.css file the following class after removing the comments...

```
 .ui-widget-header {
                  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                  background: #cccccc;
                  color: #222222;
                 font-weight: bold;
                   }
```

Now I noticed this class name:

```
      .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
               border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
               background: #e6e6e6;
               font-weight: normal;
               color: #555555;
                  }
```

How would .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default be implemented? Would the ui-state-default override the ui-widget-header if they both are implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default` rule targets the elements with class `ui-state-default` **inside** the elements with class `ui-widget-header`. If you implement these two classes on same element:

```
<div class="ui-widget-header ui-state-default"></div>
```

You will only see the effect of the rule `.ui-widget-header` on the `div`. However, in case you have markup like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget-header">
   <div class="ui-widget-header ui-state-default"></div>
</div>
```

You will see the effect of the second rule on inner `div`: the first one will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery.com

> .ui-widget-header: Class to be applied to header containers. Applies
>   header container styles to an element and its child text, links, and
>   icons.
>
> .ui-state-default: Class to be applied to clickable button-like
>   elements. Applies "clickable default" container styles to an element
>   and its child text, links, and icons.

So

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
               border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
               background: #e6e6e6;
               font-weight: normal;
               color: #555555;
                  }
```

applies to an clickable button-like element with the class .ui-state-default inside an header container with the class .ui-widget-header.